# How to import <chrono> to work with avr-gcc

Tags: c++, time, timer, c++-chrono, avr-gcc

According to [Using <chrono> as a timer in bare-metal microcontroller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736323/using-chrono-as-a-timer-in-bare-metal-microcontroller) is easy to use std::chrono with microcontrollers.

My problem is that avr-gcc (gcc for avr microcontrollers) has disabled chrono (and many others c++ features). How can I use chrono with avr-gcc?

Differents options:

1.- Copy std::chrono for another version of gcc.

2.- Write my own version of std::chrono.

3.- Forget about std::chrono and read time the C way.

4.- ...???

Comment: Do you mean chrono is not supported instead of you said disabled? There is a list of supported modules for avr-libc https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/ch20.html

Comment: Yes, it is not supported (sorry for my english). avr-libc doesn't support a lot of C++ features (I think it is normal, because avr-libc is a C library and not C++).

Comment: Then you should implement you own library or use other can fit you problem. I would recommend you for soon questions to include information about your device.

Comment: Maybe someone wrote something that you need :)

Comment: https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-libc-and-timeh-whats-deal-timeh

Comment: https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/include/time.h

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Copy std::chrono for another version of gcc.

This will not help you because there are some™ dependencies.  Here on x86_64:

```sh
echo '#include <chrono>' | g++ -fsyntax-only -xc++ - -H
```

will print quite some headers:

```
. /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/chrono
.. /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/ratio
... /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/type_traits
.... /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h
..... /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h
...... /usr/include/features.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
........ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
........ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/long-double.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
........ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
..... /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/cpu_defines.h
... /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/cstdint
.... /install/gcc-8-host/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.0.1/include/stdint.h
..... /usr/include/stdint.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wchar.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdint-intn.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdint-uintn.h
.. /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/limits
.. /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/ctime
... /usr/include/time.h
.... /install/gcc-8-host/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.0.1/include/stddef.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/timex.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_timeval.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/clock_t.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/time_t.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_tm.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_timespec.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/clockid_t.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/timer_t.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_itimerspec.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/locale_t.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__locale_t.h
.. /install/gcc-8-host/include/c++/8.0.1/bits/parse_numbers.h
```

None of these are distributed with avr-g++ because libstdc++-v3 is disabled for avr.

Moreover, depending which features you are using, you'll need modules like [libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/chrono.cc?revision=279813&view=markup) which drag further dependencies, in particular from an assumed, underlying operating system which you do not have with avr-g++ (which is bare metal).

> 2. Write my own version of std::chrono.

What would be the benefit of that? You thing you could just copy-paste code from some host computer and it's supposed to work without any problems?

> 3. Forget about std::chrono and read time the C way.

IMO, the only reasonable way to go. You want to have control over system resources.

Comment: I wrote my own version of std::chrono from scratch and it works fine.